# Get the total from td in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to calculate the total amount from the class. Im using  below function but im getting wrong output like below

```
7,240.00,640.00,8,440.00,10,940.00
```

But my expected output is sum of all

```
7,240.00+640.00+8,440.00+10,940.00 = Total
```

**Jquery**  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/irfanfiddle/pbo5bker/1/)

```
var PITotalAMount = 0;   
$(".HomePIAmtTot").each( function(){
          PITotalAMount += $(this).html();
});

 console.log(PITotalAMount);
```

How can i achieve this ? What im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `,` from the fetched html, use `.parseFloat()` to convert to floating number and then do the addition:

```
$(".HomePIAmtTot").each( function(){
      PITotalAMount += parseFloat($(this).html().replace(",",""));
});

console.log(PITotalAMount.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x0ge9cus/)**

Comment: working like a charm and thanks for your explantion too

Comment: once site will allow accept ur answer ill do that thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Change this code

```
$(this).html();
```

Into

```
parseFloat($(this).html().replace(",",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution :( notice the + sign , which when added before a string , it becomes a number)

```
  var PITotalAMount = 0;   
$(".HomePIAmtTot").each( function(){
          PITotalAMount += +$(this).html().replace(",","");
});

   console.log(PITotalAMount);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pbo5bker/3/

Comment: what about parsing value

Comment: @MilindAnantwar didnt i understand the question ?  it does sums up the numbers

Comment: @MilindAnantwar yes :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `html()` returns a string, so you need to convert it to a number.

```
var PITotalAMount = 0;   
$(".HomePIAmtTot").each( function(){
    PITotalAMount += parseFloat($(this).html().replace(',', ''));
});

console.log(PITotalAMount);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to:

1. remove the commas
2. parse the text (not html!) in the `td` to a number, and add it.

my suggestion:

```
var PITotalAMount = 0;  
$(".HomePIAmtTot").each( function(){
      PITotalAMount += parseInt($(this).text().replace(',',''));
});
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you Should parse the value when get from an html element, and need to replace "," with null to pase the correct price, so try this...

```
var PITotalAMount = 0;   
$(".HomePIAmtTot").each( function(){
      PITotalAMount += parseFloat($(this).html().replace(',', '')); 
     //alert(PITotalAMount);
});
console.log(PITotalAMount);
```

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/pbo5bker/4/)  is the Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

This is it.

```
var PITotalAMount = 0;   
$(".HomePIAmtTot").each( function(){
    PITotalAMount += parseInt($(this).html().replace(/,/g , ""));
});
console.log('Total' + PITotalAMount);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/irfanfiddle/pbo5bker/1/